# How to init setup on a Parameterized class test?

Tags: java, integration-testing, junit4

I have 2 concrete classes that implements the same interface. There are tests that are the same for both, so I want to do 1 Parameterized class test. The **classes requires to be configured initially only once** (with the same setup), so this is my workaround:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyInterfaceTest {

    private MyInterface i;
    private static boolean setupDone[] = new boolean[2]; //this is ugly

    public MyInterfaceTest(MyInterface i) {
        this.i = i;
        if(i instanceof ImplA && !setupDone[0]){
            setup();
            setupDone[0] = true;
        }else if(i instanceof ImplB && !setupDone[1]){
            setup();
            setupDone[1] = true;
        }
        //must add code here for more Impl -> ugly
    }


    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getParameters()
    {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { new ImplA() },
                { new ImplB() }
        });
    }

    //tets...

}
```

Which is quite ugly. What is a better solution?

Comment: For your getParameters method, do you need to be returning an `Object` collection? You could simply change your array typing to `<MyInterface>` to avoid that cast you do in the constructor.

Comment: The cast I do is to determine which Impl is `i`

Comment: Yes, but since they both inherit `MyInterface`'s methods then you probably don't need to. If you need to test methods that `MyInterface` has, then you can call on an array of `MyInterface` objects without a cast. You only need the cast *if* the implementations have other unique method names and you need to test those too.

Comment: No. My objective is to setup each Impl once. If I re-setup thats wrong. It must be done only once.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I just misunderstand how your setup for each implementation is done.

Comment: Why don't you make your `setup()` method static then, and in your `getParameters()` method, before you return the impls, initialize them with your static `setup()` method?

Comment: Not exactly, because I should declare MyInterace as static too, but thats it! Thank you @nickb

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ServiceLocator1Test {

    private MyInterface i;

    public MyInterfaceTest(MyInterface i) {
        this.i = i;
    }


    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getParameters()
    {
        MyInterface a = new ImplA(); setup(a);
        MyInterface b = new ImplB(); setup(b);

        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { a },
                { b }
        });
    }

    //tets...

}

private static void setup(MyInterface myinterface){/*...*/}
```